# How to correctly set-up Amazon SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up my Amazon SES with PHP and I was led to a github that already does this found here: https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses

I'm having difficulty getting it to work and am unsure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone with experience give me some insight on what to do further? It says that it is sending the e-mail but when I check my inbox nothing is happening. Below is my code:

```
require_once('src/SimpleEmailService.php');
require_once('src/SimpleEmailServiceMessage.php');
require_once('src/SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php');
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('myaccessid', 'myaccesskey');
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('jason@aol.com');
$m->setFrom('Name <coupons@oncoint.com>');
$m->setSubject('You have got Email!');
$m->setMessageFromString('Your message');
$ses->sendEmail($m);
```

Comment: Did you verify your From email address? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

Comment: Hello, that is correct. I verified the from address. I did not verify my DKIM though and wasn't sure if I actually need it to send e-mails.

Comment: I also tried just sending the addTo to the verified e-mail and am still not receiving an e-mail.

Comment: When you say that it is "sending the e-mail", how are you determining that?

Comment: Does the SES console show that any emails have been sent? Did you check your spam folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to not use any class created and just use the SDK straight out of the box, here is a working code;

```
// Include AWS SDK for PHP

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/php/awssdk/aws-autoloader.php";
require($path);

// Instantiate an SES instance

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'your key',
            'secret' => 'your secret',
            'region' => 'your region'
        ));

//Now that you have the client ready, you can build the message
    $msg = array();
    $msg['Source'] = "verified email";
    //ToAddresses must be an array
    $msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "verified email";

    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = "Your Subject";
    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] ="Your message";
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
    $result = $client->sendEmail($msg);
    if($result) {
        echo "Email Sent"; 
    }
```